# Use Fermat’s Theorem to prove Euler’s Theorem in the case m = pq. with p and q being two distinct prime numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euler-mascheroni-constant, fermat-numbers

If $p$ is a prime and $p$ does not divide $a$,
then $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}.$$
Since $p$ is prime, the fact that $p$ does not divide a means that $a$ and $p$ are
relatively prime. Also, $\varphi(p) = p-1$  Thus, Fermat’s Theorem follows from Euler’s
Theorem

I'm just stuck on what to do at this point any tips?

Comment: You want to prouve $a^{\phi(n)} = 1 \bmod(n)$ for $n=pq$ ?

Comment: yes I need to prove thata Since Fermat Theorem is a special case to Euler's theorm and due to this, Euler theorem is relatively the same as Fernmat

Comment: ook wait i write the proof

Comment: I'm very confused what you are trying to do.  It seems like you are trying to take FLT (a result of Eulers Th) as a given, use it to prove a special case of Euler's Theorem, *then* take the special case as a given, and use it to prove FLT.  That is circular of at least two revolutions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p,q \in \mathbb{P}$, and $a \in \mathbb{N}^*$

Suppose that $\gcd(a, pq) = 1$, Let proof that $a^{(p-1)(q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}.$

Using Fermat theoreme we have :

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} & \\
a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} & 
\end{array} \right.$$

Then :

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
a^{(p-1)(q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} & \\
a^{(q-1)(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} & 
\end{array} \right.$$

We have $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ Then $pq$ divide $a^{(p-1)(q-1)} - 1$ and that complete the proof.